# Move-ADObject Access is Denied when using limited access credentials

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have OU folders in the root of my AD that look similar to this:

```
AA
--AB
BA
```

All of these OU's contain computer accounts.  I have a computer in BA that I want to move to AB.  I am using credentials that are not Domain Admin credentials and have very limited access to resources.  The credentials have full access to AA, AB, and BA.

If my computer is in BA and I issue the following powershell command:

```
Move-ADObject -Identity $myComp -TargetPath "OU=AB,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Credentials $myCred
```

Then it fails with Access Is Denied.  However, if the same exact computer account resides in AA, then this same statement works fine.  I can also move it from AB to BA without issue.
I have verified that none of the OU's has the prevent from accidental deletion option turned on.  I can move back and forth between AA and AB, I just can't move there from an OU with a different root.

I can't think of anything else to do to diagnose.  So, I am asking for input to see if anyone else knows how to diagnose what is going on and perhaps find where the access is denied is coming from.

Comment: The account you are using needs permission to delete computer objects in OU AA and AB. Does it have that?

Comment: It does.  I confirmed full access on all OU's involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Create Computer objects and Delete Computer objects are not all the privileges required to make this work.  You also need to have Write-Property for Common-Name ({bf96793f-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}) or for Public Information ({e48d0154-bcf8-11d1-8702-00c04fb96050}).  I don't see a way to manipulate the Write Common-Name privilege, so allowing Write to Public Information seems to be the least privilege option.

If you are creating a new Computer object from a low privilege account, the easiest way to do this is to create an ACE for the OU that applies to descendant computer objects and grants the **Write public information** privilege (under **Properties:** in the Windows Server 2012 R2 ACE editor UI, but only if you restrict to **Descendant Computer objects**) to the low privilege account.  This privilege allows the name to change and, along with **Create Computer objects** on the target OU and **Delete Computer objects** on the source OU, should allow the Move-ADObject cmdlet to function as expected.